# Samba share encoding with UTF-8 issue

Tags: ubuntu, encoding, utf-8, samba

I use samba to share folder between Ubuntu and Windows. And here comes the problem that I want to use UTF-8 encoding in both Linux and Windows.

However, when I forced to encode file with UTF-8 in windows, I check the encoding in Linux, it said it was ASCII.

It automatically encoded both files and folders in Ubuntu with ASCII.

How to fix it? How to write samba configure file? `/etc/samba/smb.conf` ?

I want both windows and Ubuntu encode with UTF-8.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try in /etc/samba/smb.conf, global section:

```
dos charset = cp866
unix charset = UTF8
display charset = UTF8
```

Comment: Looking at https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/4.3/man-html/smb.conf.5.html it seems to be `utf-8` and not `utf8`. Also why would you use `cp866` if you can use `cp932` ?